# JQGrid can not load json data from action

Tags: json, jqgrid, struts

I have problem when loading data from action to jqGrid

My action return JSON data:

```
{"page":"1","records":"31","rows":["{'id':'1','cell':['1','Cant open destop','Destop','Easy','duongls','huyld','minhnq','Finance ','Open']}","{'id':'2','cell':['2','Cant log to email','Email','Normal','thangtd','minhnq','longnh','Secretary ','Assigned']}","{'id':'3','cell':['3','No internet access Edited ver 2 longnh','Connection','Hard','thangtd','longnh','longnh','Secretary ','Closed']}","{'id':'4','cell':['4','Request password','Account','Normal','dungtq','honglm','longnh','Director','Cancelled']}","{'id':'5','cell':['5','Cant open latop','Laptop','Hard','duongls','huyld','minhnq','Director','Closed']}","{'id':'6','cell':['6','issue 11111111111111','','','dungtq','longnh','','Planning','Open']}","{'id':'7','cell':['7','Issue ku minh heo','','','dungtq','longnh','','Planning','Open']}","{'id':'8','cell':['8','New ticket 12345','','','dungtq','longnh','','Planning','Open']}","{'id':'9','cell':['9','Mail server cannot connect','','','haitct','longnh','','Director','Open']}","{'id':'10','cell':['10','aaaaaaaaaaaa','','','dungtq','longnh','','Planning','Open']}"],"total":"4"}
```

and in JSP I call jqgrid:

```
$("#list1").jqGrid({                  
        url: "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/pagingIssue?time='+new Date().getTime()",
        colNames:['Id','Name', 'Type','Severity', 'Owner','Register', 'Responsor', 'Department','Status'],
        colModel:[
               {name:'issId',index:'issId', width:40,sortable:true},
               {name:'issName',index:'issName', width:200,sortable:true},
               {name:'issType',index:'issType', width:100,sortable:true},
               {name:'issSeverity',index:'issSeverity', width:100,sortable:true},
               {name:'issOwner',index:'issOwner', width:80,sortable:true},
               {name:'issRegister',index:'issRegister', width:100,sortable:true},
               {name:'issResponsor',index:'issResponsor', width:100,sortable:true},
               {name:'department',index:'department', width:120,sortable:true},
               {name:'issStatus',index:'issStatus', width:80,sortable:true}],
       rowNum:10,
       rowList:[10,15,20],
       pager: '#pager1',
       sortname: 'issId',
       datatype: 'json',
       recordpos: 'left',
       viewrecords: true,
       sortorder: 'desc',
       multiselect: true,
       caption: 'Issue List' });
});
```

The grid just show Loading...
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

By default, your JSON data should be in the format noted in the jqGrid documentation for [JSON Data](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data):

```
{ 
  "total": "xxx", 
  "page": "yyy", 
  "records": "zzz",
  "rows" : [
    {"id" :"1", "cell" :["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]},
    {"id" :"2", "cell":["cell21", "cell22", "cell23"]},
      ...
  ]
}
```

Your data is close, but `rows` contains a string

```
"rows":["{'id' ... ]}"]
```

instead of an object:

```
"rows":[{'id' ... ]}]
```

---

Also, you should always use double quotes for strings, and never single-quotes (see the state machine diagrams at [json.org](http://json.org/) for more details). So your JSON should look like this:

```
"rows":[{"id" ... ]}]
```

Comment: +1: I agree and wanted to write almost the same answer. The only thing is that one should use `"` instead of `'` to have valid JSON data (I mean that you should change `"rows":[{'id' ... ]}]` to `"rows":[{"id": "1", "cell": ["1",... ]}, ...]`)